# data structure design for several parallel information C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have question for how to store information with parallel level.
I set a vector to store each line information.
a segment will be:

```
segment number(int), true/false(bool), associated ID<1,2...>(set<int>)
```

I have several segments to put in one line, so these segments are parallel information.

There are several lines to store....

is there some good structure to store them? class, or struct will be OK. thanks a lot!

Comment: What is a segment? Can you explain what you mean by 'parallel level'?

Comment: sorry for my poor explanation. segment, may be called element, which stores numbers, associated ID, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
struct segment 
{
int number;
bool boolean;
std::set<int> associated_ids;
};
```

Comment: so I store all of them as vector<segment*>?

Comment: Have you tried? There is lots of documentation on how to use `std::vector` out there. Here's a starting point: http://www.mochima.com/tutorials/vectors.html

Comment: yes, I know. Because I need to use these segment information in other place. So, it is not good to copy the whole structure to every place. That's why I use pointers, is it good?

Comment: Yes, if you do not forget to release the memory.

Answer (score 0):

What difference between "parallel information" and "serial information" in your vision?

You mean this is as parallel:

```
struct segment 
{
int number;
bool boolean;
std::set<int> associated_ids;
};

std::vector <segment> v;
```

and this is as serial:

```
std::vector<int> number;
std::vector<bool> number;
std::vector< std::set<int> > associated_ids;
```

?

Or it's a smth else?